# Commercially supported alternatives to Microsoft Exchange

Tags: windows, linux, email, collaboration

I'm looking for a fully collaborative alternative to Microsoft Exchange that will allow for Outlook functionality (shared Calendars, Contacts, Note, Public Folders) and mobile device active sync style connectivity.

I just finished a failed MailEnable migration attempt. So, that one is out.

I realize that this probably means going with Linux (which I'm comfortable with), but I do not want a totally open source product. I would like to have some commercial support channel if needed.

However, it seems that some of these packages are more of a premises based subscription. Being entrenched in the SMB market, I need something that would be a one-time purchase with perhaps annual support and maybe periodic version upgrade options.

Please chime in if you have a favorite that has provided you with a fairly painless migration process.

Comment: *I do not want a totally open source product* why is this a problem for you?

Comment: _I do not want a totally open source product. I would like to have some commercial support channel if needed._
The two aren't mutually exclusive (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_models_for_open-source_software#Approaches)

Answer (score 0):

Based on this 
*"....a fully collaborative alternative to Microsoft Exchange that will allow for Outlook functionality (shared Calendars, Contacts, Note, Public Folders) and mobile device active sync style connectivity."*

I think you should try Mailsite, all your needs are there. I have use Mailsite for several years now and it's working well.

http://www.mailsite.com/EmailServerFeatures/

I hope it help's.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a small scale [OX service](https://www.open-xchange.com/) in the past. It is pretty painless to set up and comes with a very robust feature set. Also comes with commercial support if needed.